# How can I clean hidden characters?

Tags: c#, json

I came across this bug to day where the JSON parser is not able to parse the incoming string. I have snippet out the problem.

Code:

```
    var str = "}​}";

    foreach (var ch in str)
        Console.WriteLine($"Char: {ch} ({((byte)ch)})");

    Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to quit ...");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
Char: } (125)
Char: ? (11)
Char: } (125)
Press [ENTER] to quit ...
```

As you can see(or not see :-)) there is a character between the two `}}`.

How can I clean this? This comes from a message that is received in my Azure Function, so I have little control over the input. The only thing I can do is to clean it after receive it.

Comment: The character with decimal value 11 is a vertical tab character. See e.g. asciitable.com. You might want to look at why that's being inserted.

Comment: On further inspection the byte sequence of bytes for the invisible character is [0xe2,0x80,0x8b]. 3 bytes mean it's UTF-8. Looking up this byte sequence reveals that this is a [zero-width space (U+200B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) that's why you can't see it. Unfortunately I think this invalidates the JSON which is why the parser fails to parse it.

Comment: ... Have you any control over the incoming JSON? That would be the best place to fix this issue by making sure it's not there in the first place. If not raise it as a bug before having to hack around invalid JSON.

Comment: @phuzi How did you get a ZWJ there? When I copy that `}}` into a hex editor, I just get the two `}` characters, so I think something probably got lost somewhere.

Comment: @canton7 I copied the characters and pasted in to a hex editor - hexed.it - https://hexed.it/#base64:feKAi30= this showed a sequence of 5 bytes. You could also see the escaped unicode in Cyberchef - https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Escape_Unicode_Characters('%5C%5Cu',false,4,true)&input=feKAi30

Comment: Exactly what I did, then. Odd

Comment: By the way, a `char` is a 16-bit value, so cast it to `short` instead of (8-bit) `byte` - revealing value 8203

Comment: Aah I missed the `(byte)` cast - assumed it was `char` and moved on. That explains it nicely, good spot.